# httpwebrequest in dotnet core returns 404 error

Tags: c#, web-scraping, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I am new with dotnet-core.
I am doing some **scraping** requesting code. My previous practice with AliExpress is working fine for me with same pattern
Now, I am stuck with Walmart requests

When I am using following code with any other website it returns me OK response and required data.

```
 HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            // wRequest.Timeout = 10000
            wRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/ 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, Like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
           

            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());

                   var responseString= sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Debug.Write(responseString);
                }
            }

       }
```

but when I am doing it with Walmart it returns me 404 not found error.
more strange thing is following (another) code is working for me over Walmart with C# and dotnet Core 2.1 framework in one console project.
When I am importing it into main project it again returns 404 error.

```
WebClient wReq = new WebClinet();    
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(wReq.DownloadString(URL));
```

I have used all headers found via fiddler and cookies container even. But no luck. I cant understand what the issue is.

**PS:** I have tried to use some code above which is rejecting for Walmart with another (some random) marketplace URL it works for me. But no luck with Walmart.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information for anyone stuck in same or similar issue.
My URL for Walmart was not right.
I was checking URL by dividing it into part like Authority, query string etc.
and then combining it back.
During combination addition "/" was adding at the end of URL and it becomes invalid.
so, removing that did the trick.